# Stuck in migrating Google App Engine project to Java 11

Tags: google-app-engine, java-11, migrate

I've just started looking at migrating a Google App Engine project from Java 8 to Java 11.  The project is in Eclipse.

There doesn't appear to be a Java 11 option in the Project Facets.

[image]

If I try to create a new GAE project there is no option there either.

[image]

Note that Java 11 is installed. Eclipse was started with Java 11.  I'm also using the latest GCTE.

Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to check the below comment? Also I have updated my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Github Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3710#issuecomment-1477001825), at the moment Java 11/17 support for the App Engine standard on Cloud Tools for Eclipse is not available. You may consider using [Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/using-maven)/[Gradle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle) plugins for now. Also you can add your concern to the same issue.

And as per the comment in this [Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2665#issuecomment-1433322374),

> We are currently in the process of prioritizing this work, we will update in this thread. Thanks!

Looks like the team is working on it. Keep an eye on it for further updates.

Also feel free to raise a [Public issue tracker](http://www.issuetracker.google.com) or [Feature request](http://www.issuetracker.google.com) describing your concern.  You can use [this page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) for reference when creating an issue.

Comment: That post is from over two years ago.  At this point, Java 8 will only be supported on GAE until Jan 2024.  If there is no Eclipse support now it seems like it won't happen ever.

Comment: @MikeDee I have checked the [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2665#issuecomment-1433322374) the issue is still open and the last comment was made in February and I have updated my answer. Can you have a look at it now?